# NodeJS get last line of file everytime file is changed

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, fs

I've tried doing the below, but fs.watch only gets called when the file is modified and I look at the test.txt file in notepad++
I'm trying to get it too be called without me opening test.txt in notepad for the function to be called

```
const fs = require("fs");
const dir = "test.txt"
fs.watch(dir, (eventType, filename) => {
  fs.readFile(dir, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {

    let lines = data.trim().split("\n")
    console.log(lines[lines.length - 1])
  });
});
```

Comment: Use fs.watchFile() instead

Comment: Aah that was it, if you wanna post an answer with that, i'll accept it, thanks.

Comment: What OS are you using? How do you modify test.txt?

Comment: This is really dependant on what OS you are using, `watch` will leverage different APIs depending on the platform. What platform are you running on and how are you interacting with the files?

Comment: I'm using windows, and another program writes to the file and I just want to get the last line of the file. fs.watchFile did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

I needed the same thing and I combine your code with this one: [Catch file changes](https://thisdavej.com/how-to-watch-for-files-changes-in-node-js/) . And here is my code:

```
const md5 = require('md5');
console.log('Watching for file changes on ${txt_path}');
let md5Previous = null;
let fsWait = false;
let count = 0;
fs.watch(txt_path, (event , filename) => {
    if(filename){
        if(fsWait) return;
        fsWait = setTimeout( () => {
            fsWait = false;
        }, 100);
        const md5Current = md5(fs.readFileSync(txt_path));
        if (md5Current === md5Previous) {
            return;
        }
        md5Previous = md5Current;
        console.log(`${filename} file Changed`);
        fs.readFile(txt_path, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            let lines = data.trim().split("\n")
            console.log(lines[lines.length - 1])
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use file stream to make your own watcher which will be triggered every 10 seconds. You can also add your logic into it.

```
const fs = require('fs');

let previousLine = '';

const readFile = function (path) {
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(path, { encoding: 'utf8' });
  let lastLine = '';

  fileStream.on('data', function (value) {
     let linesInStream = value.split(/[\r\n]+/g);
     lastLine = linesInStream[linesInStream.length - 1];
  });

  fileStream.on('end', function () {
    /* will print only when there is change in file content */
    if (lastLine !== previousLine) {
        previousLine = lastLine;
        console.log(lastLine);
    }
  });
};

const waitTime = 10000; // 10 seconds wait

setInterval(function () {
   readFile('C:\\data.log');
}, waitTime);
```

Comment: This is _far_ more inefficient than `watch` or a similar implementation, you're reading the entire file every 10 seconds as opposed to only reading the file when something has changed.